# rbenv in production triggering mongodb connection error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, ubuntu, bundler, rbenv

I've switched to rbenv in production (staging to be correct) and most of the switch seemed to work just fine. I've followed the guidelines outlined here: http://blog.danielpietzsch.com/post/14005159872/running-a-rails-app-in-production-using-rbenv-apache

However, running `rake assets:precompile` throws this **Failed to connect to a master node at localhost:27017**. My guess is that this is a symptom of something else missing or being astray.

**which rake**

```
root@staging1:/var/www/staging# which rake
/usr/local/rbenv/shims/rake
```

**rbenv version**

```
root@staging1:/var/www/staging# rbenv version
1.9.3-p125 (set by /usr/local/rbenv/version)
```

**mongod is running on localhost:27017**

```
root@staging1:/var/www/staging# mongo --port 27017 --host localhost
MongoDB shell version: 1.8.0
connecting to: localhost:27017/test
> exit
bye
```

**rake task that triggers the error**

```
root@staging1:/var/www/staging# rake assets:precompile
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby /usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
rake aborted!
Failed to connect to a master node at localhost:27017  <--------------- ERROR

Tasks: TOP => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p125/bin/r...]

Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Here is the rake task with --trace: http://pastie.org/private/ww9wm0wlm6le6wbtmq89ia

I've found a few others with the same problem on heroku, but in that case it seem to be because mongo really isn't running: http://blog.noizeramp.com/2011/10/14/rails-3-asset-pipeline-on-heroku-when-using-mongoid/

I'd be happy to provide more details if needed. Just let me know and I'll update the question with more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was using this in my mongoid.yml:

```
defaults: &defaults
  use_utc: true
  host: localhost
  allow_dynamic_fields: false
  ...
```

and in /etc/mongodb.conf:

```
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
```

This doesn't work, for some reason. Changing to 127.0.0.1 solved the problem.